# BigQuery Filter by Date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-analysis

I want to filter my data as per the DATE and TIME format **'2016-01-09 16:31:04.000 UTC'** using Legacy SQL in BigQuery. Kindly help me out with the correct syntax. I'm stuck.

Code

```
SELECT *
FROM
[table.column] AS Alias
WHERE
date >  '2017-03-31Z';
```

Comment: Try to provide example code snippets, show your code.

Comment: SELECT * FROM [table_name] 
where date  BETWEEN '2016-01-09 16:31:04.000 UTC' AND

Comment: Simply update your question instead of putting the code in comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `type` of your column is `timestamp` then,

```
SELECT timestamp
FROM [bigquery-public-data:openaq.global_air_quality]
where timestamp > '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
```

If the `type` of the column is `string, then you can try,

```
SELECT timestamp
FROM [bigquery-public-data:openaq.global_air_quality]
where timestamp(timestamp) > timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00')
```

For more BigQuery Legacy SQL functions go [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql)